# XSLT: Get all children of parents with specified attributes

Tags: xslt, transform

**Given this XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" ?>
<r>
    <products start="5" stop="8">
        <p>
            <id> 50 </id>
            <name> Murphy </name>
            <price> 33 </price>
        </p>
        <p>
            <id> 10 </id>
            <name> Margarethe </name>
            <price> 11 </price>
        </p>
    </products>
    <products start="1" stop="4">
        <p>
            <id> 555 </id>
            <name> XXXX</name>
            <price> 333 </price>
        </p>
        <p>
            <id> 10 </id>
            <name> Mexico </name>
            <price> 11 </price>
        </p>
    </products>
    <products start="1" stop="4">
        <p>
            <id> 30 </id>
            <name> HKoney </name>
            <price> 11 </price>
        </p>
        <p>
            <id> 10 </id>
            <name> HMargarethe </name>
            <price> 11 </price>
        </p>
    </products>
</r>
```

---

**With this XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="products[@start &lt; 2 and @stop &gt; 2]" >
    <xsl:call-template name="test"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="test">
     <test><xsl:value-of select="*/name"/></test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="products"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Having this output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test> XXXX</test>
<test> HKoney </test>
```

---

> **Q : Why am I not getting all the `<p>` with parent of specified attributes, only the first one? `Mexico` and `HMargarethe` was expected also.**

---

**Desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test> XXXX</test>
<test> Mexico </test>
<test> HKoney </test>
<test> HMargerethe</test>
```

---

> **NOTE: I wish to have it working without `for-each` loop.**

Comment: Do you want all the names within a single <p> element to appear inside <test>?
Please provide an example of the desired output

Comment: I have put desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using `apply-templates` directly on the `<name>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="products[@start &lt; 2 and @stop &gt; 2]" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p/name"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <test>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </test>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="products"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to process all `p` elements, see the `xsl:for-each` here:

```
<xsl:template name="test">
    <test>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </test>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I forgot to specifiy that I don't want `for-eac h` involved

Comment: What's the problem of `for-each`? I am just curious. By the way, your output example is not a valid XML file because it doesn't contain its root element.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q : Why am I not getting all the `<p>` with parent of specified attributes, only the first one? `Mexico` and `HMargarethe` was expected also.**

Notice that template `test` only called once for each `products` element :

```
<xsl:template match="products[@start &lt; 2 and @stop &gt; 2]" >
    <xsl:call-template name="test"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Each time the template called, you pull multiple `name` elements to be processed by `<xsl:value-of>`. And according to MSDN regarding `select` attribute of [`<xsl:value-of>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> Required. The Expressions (XML) to be evaluated against the current context. The results are converted to a string, as by a call to the string() function. **A node-set is converted to a string by inserting the string value of the *first node* in the set**.

The specification also tells the same story, see W3C [xslt `value-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of) and [xpath function `string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string)

Answer (score 1):

Have modified the code for not to use for loop

Please use below code ,it works as expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/" name ="ParentCopy">
<xsl:param name="LoopCountA">1</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name = "Count" >
        <xsl:value-of select = "count(r/products)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test ="($LoopCountA  &lt;= $Count) ">
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test ="r/products[$LoopCountA][@start &lt; 2 and @stop &gt; 2]">
                <test>
    <xsl:value-of select = "r/products[$LoopCountA]/p[1]/name"/>
                </test> 
<test>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "r/products[$LoopCountA]/p[2]/name"/>
</test>
            </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
    <xsl:call-template name="ParentCopy">
            <xsl:with-param name="LoopCountA">
<xsl:value-of select="$LoopCountA + 1"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Let me know for any other queries

Comment: looking for solution without `for-each`

Comment: Unfortunately the topic is closed and solved :) . For further notice try googling node-set() function it's very helpful. Also you can write users name with `@` like @sreevathsa a

Comment: @Dajilido, Thx for the info. but still any how the above xsl will work as expected without using for-each loop.